# use of IPC in Cpp in Android

Tags: c++, android

after having a bit  exploring at Android2.2 source code,I get to know Android Framework works with large number of IPC mechanisms written in Cpp, such as CameraService,MediaService and etc.

I also see those many key classes drive these IPC mechanisms, such as IInterface, BpInterface, BnInterface, Binder, IBinder, RefBase and lots of others...

I now want to write my IPC-Service in cpp ( not in Java using AIDL ) , unfortunately, I cannot  find out any helpful resources(articles, tutorials, books and so on) that thoroughly detail use of these classes

anyone who is proficient in this aspect, can u give me ideas?

thanks!

Comment: This is actually going to be difficult - not only are the format of the underlying calls subject to change, there's no apparent mechanism for an unprivileged process to register with the Binder driver in the kernel.  Ordinarily, your dalvik inherits a registration from zygote, and has the necessary binder threads to manage it.  If your native code tries to channel additional operations through that binder registration, you may very well confuse dalvik's binder threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is basically no documentation on these, since they are not part of the public SDK/NDK.  If you are working at this level, you are doing platform development; the documentation is for the most part the rest of the platform and the source code of the things you are using.

You will find these a *lot* rougher to use than the Binder APIs in the SDK.  For example, aidl can not currently generate C++ interfaces, so you will have to write all of your interface stubs by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Why use C++ when the Android SDK provides you all you need, wrapped up in a device-independent package?  The Android SDK is Java, if you want to use C++ you are going to be in for a long haul esp. if you want hardware access.

If you really want to investigate this, check out the [Native Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Comment: The obvious answer for why would be to skip the overhead of passing thing up to dalvik only to have it pass them back to native code.  But the ndk doesn't really support this.

Comment: hey, steve,  SDK and NDK are used only in App development,I am porting Anroid to my device

Comment: Agreed.  afai can see Google have removed the Platform Guide, which is what you would need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this help.But I'm trying [Generating C++ Binder Interfaces with aidl-cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/aidl/+/master/docs/aidl-cpp.md)

some content here :

> Build Interface
>   Write AIDL in .aidl files and add them to LOCAL_SRC_FILES in your Android.mk. If your build target is a binary (e.g. you include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)), then the generated code will be C++, not Java.
>   AIDL definitions should be hosted from the same repository as the implementation. Any system that needs the definition will also need the implementation (for both parcelables and interface). If there are multiple implementations (i.e. one in Java and one in C++), keep the definition with the native implementation. Android now has systems that run the native components of the system without the Java.
>   If you use an import statement in your AIDL, even from the same package, you need to add a path to LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES. This path should be relative to the root of the Android tree. For instance, a file IFoo.aidl defining com.example.IFoo might sit in a folder hierarchy something/something-else/com/example/IFoo.aidl. Then we would write:
>   LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES := something/something-else